# Java! How to go to the specific line?

Tags: java

I just started to code in Java and I have a question. After my "else" statement, I want to repeat my code again. How do I do that? Is there a keyword or something?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInputStory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        userinput:
        System.out.println("Enter you name:");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("OK! Now enter your age:");
        int age;
        age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Good! And the city you live in, please:");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String city = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("So, let's check");
        System.out.println(
                "Your name is " + name + ". You are " + age + " years old and you currently live in " + city + ".");
        System.out.println("Is that right?");

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yesno = inp.nextLine();
        if (yesno.equals("yes") || yesno.equals("Yes") || yesno.equals("YES")) {
            System.out.println("Great job!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Let's try again then!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks a minimal understanding of the topic and does not show any research effort

Comment: basically [a simple google search gives the solution](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java+repeat+code) in about 5 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the body of your code that you want repeating inside a [`while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop and `break` when your end-condition is true:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        userinput:

        System.out.println("Enter you name:");

        String name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("OK! Now enter your age:");

        int age;

        age = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Good! And the city you live in, please:");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String city = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("So, let's check");
        System.out.println("Your name is " + name + ". You are " + age + " years old and you currently live in " + city + ".");
        System.out.println("Is that right?");

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

        String yesno = inp.nextLine();

        if (yesno.equals("yes") || yesno.equals("Yes") || yesno.equals("YES")) {
            System.out.println("Great job!");
            break;
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Let's try again then!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can envelop our whole code by:

```
while(1)
```

ut its not a good approach and there must be some condition applied (depending upon the xontext of your program) which can take you out of the loop